# -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; working on one style sheet, but not the other?

Tags: css

Okay this code works for something simple I threw together as a POC:

```
.linedcircle
{
width:668px;
height:668px;
background:url(https://robertsspaceindustries.com/rsi/static/images/error/lined_circle.png);
position:relative;
margin: 10px auto 0;
animation:rotating 8s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation:rotating 10s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes rotating {
0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating
{
0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

The circle spins ad infinitum and there are generally no problems. However with this code on a different style sheet:

```
.burna{
    animation:fadein 0.50s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 0.50s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
0%{opacity:0;}
40%{opacity:1;}
50%{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@keyframes fadein {
0%{opacity:0;}
40%{opacity:1;}
50%{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
```

the animation only plays once. I originally thought it was my javascript or something of that nature but its not. I can change the iteration count to whatever I want and it still only ever plays the animation once. It is working perfectly on Firefox, just not on Chrome, and I THINK Ive tracked it down to the CSS itself, but everything looks correct. So Im not entirely sure what Im doing wrong here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order on the CSS file sometimes is important, in your second example first make the declaration for the `animation` and then the other properties like `iteration-count`:

```
-webkit-animation:fadein 0.50s; /*This first*/
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
```

The **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Dgv/3/)**

Comment: Gah, its always the stupidest little things. Thank you very much!